# Concatenate layers in R Keras

Tags: r, keras, bert-language-model

I have this BERT classifier, where I  want to concatenate the BERT output with additional features (hot-coded, 13 categories).

I get this error message which I do not understand - the arguments specified are all named.

```
input_word_ids <- layer_input(shape = c(set.max_length), dtype = 'int32', name = "input_word_ids")
input_mask <- layer_input(shape = c(set.max_length), dtype = 'int32', name = "input_attention_mask")
input_topic <- layer_input(shape = c(13), dtype = 'int32', name = "input_topic")

last_hidden_state <- model_tf(input_word_ids, attention_mask = input_mask)[[1]] # shape=(None, 512, 768)
cls_token <- last_hidden_state[, 1,] # shape=(None, 768)

output <- cls_token %>%
  layer_concatenate(inputs = list(cls_token, input_topic), axis = -1)
```

```
Error in assert_all_dots_named(envir, cl) : 
  All arguments provided to `...` must be named.
Call with unnamed arguments in dots:
  layer_concatenate(inputs = list(cls_token, input_topic), axis = -1, .)
```

If I run `layer_concatenate(inputs = list(cls_token, input_topic))` [without the axis argument],
I get

```
Error in modifiers[[nm]](args[[nm]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'integer'
```

The first error message stems from the Keras package (assert_all_dots_named(), line 435, https://github.com/rstudio/keras/blob/main/R/utils.R) if I am not mistaken

I read the Keras vignette, I don't see what I am doing wrong...

Any help is highly appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it on my own - `cls_token %>%` was the problem. A conflict of Keras functional api and maggritr-piping I suppose. `cls_token %>%` was used by layer_concatenate() as another "unnamed" input, therefore the error message.

Solution:

```
output <- layer_concatenate(inputs = list(cls_token, input_topic), axis = 1) %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = set.dropout)
```